# How to pass object as a query param in spring data REST

Tags: spring, converters, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am having a EmailRepository which queries for a person like follows

```
findByPerson(Person person);
```

The spring-data-rest `/search` resource list the following href

```
http://localhost:8080/emailAddresses{?person}
```

How to make a curl command for the above search url in GET method? Also if the person does not exists, I need to throw "PersonNotFoundException".

I am using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.3.3.RELEASE

Comment: Can anyone provide me a curl command to find emailAddress by person

Answer (score 0):

Try the below curl commands -

1. if you are using path param -

   curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -k "http://localhost:8080/emailAddresses/person"
2. if you are using query param -

   curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -k "http://localhost:8080/emailAddresses?person=aaa"

Comment: I am using person as a queryparam. This person param is a object. How to pass an object as a param

Comment: You can send required Person class fields in the query param separating with '&' and build person object inside your service by retrieving the values from query params. I am not sure you can pass object as param.